# Is there a way to register Jupyter Notebook Progress Bar Widget instead of Text Progress Bar in Dask/Distributed?

Tags: python, dask

I know that there is a way to globally register `dask.diagnostics.ProgressBar`, and while it is quite nice, it breaks my cell outputs. I have also seen a nice `distributed.diagnostics.progress` function, which can present the execution progress with Jupyter Notebook Progress Bar widget, but it expects to receive futures.

The issue I have here is that `dask.diagnostics.ProgressBar` uses `stdout` (so I cannot print anything while I use the Progress Bar), and `distributed.diagnostics.progress` needs to be called explicitly with Dask/Distributed futures, but I have my functions which compute something and return an instance of a "result" class rather than a Dask/Distributed future.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer today is "no".  This is possible to build, but would require some effort on your part.

The `distributed.diagnostics.progress` function operates in the event loop, and so it stops updating when notebook is busy running a cell.  There is no way to both have a synchronous dask.compute experience (you give a graph, it gives a result) and also use the IPython widget progressbar produced by `distributed.diagnostics.progress`.

However, both the single machine and distributed machine schedulers have plugin systems (which is how we built the progressbars) so it should be possible to extend either system if you'd like to build your own:

- http://dask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/diagnostics.html
- http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins.html

Comment: Could you please clarify the situation around "There is no way to both have a synchronous dask.compute experienceand also use the IPython widget progressbar"? Is it some sort of Jupyter Notebook widgets limitation, Dask/Distributed limitation, or just a non-implemented feature? (P.S. You have posted 2 exactly the same links in your answer; did you mean to link Distributed documentation?)

Comment: It's not a fundamental limitation.  We just can't wait entirely on a threading event.  Instead we need to give control back to the Tornado IOLoop that runs the Jupyter notebook from time to time.  The `sync` call blocks until the computation finishes.  If we want a Jupyter plugin to update then we can't block.  One solution would be to block-with-timeout in a loop.

Comment: An alternative would be to build an IPython widget based plugin for the single machine scheduler.